# R shiny: How can I make a popup in the leaflet for R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, popup

I am using some data to produce a map with markers in certain places and using the popup function to output a value.

The data I am getting is from sql, following is the code for that:

```
ui <- dashboardBody(
      tabItem(tabName = "leaflet",
              actionButton("gomap", "Display map!"),
              h2("Map of restaurants in London.", tags$br(), "Click on teardrop to check names."),
              leafletOutput("mymap"),
              p(),

              )
```

I am using the longitude and the latitude to make the points on map using the leaflet library.
I want to be displayed as popup a name for when the user clicks on the respected points on the map.

The code for how i produced the map and points on them with the popup for each point.

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {

points <- eventReactive(input$gomap, {
    # open DB connection
    db <- dbConnector(
      server   = getOption("database_server"),
      database = getOption("database_name"),
      uid      = getOption("database_userid"),
      pwd      = getOption("database_password"),
      port     = getOption("database_port")
    )
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(db), add = TRUE)
  
    query_leaflet <- paste0("select Longitude, Latitude from rest where name like '%",input$names,"%' and Votes between ",input$slider_votes[1]," and ", input$slider_votes[2],";")
    print(query_leaflet)
    data_leaflet <- dbGetQuery(db, query_leaflet)
    cbind(data_leaflet)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                         options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(data = points(), popup=data_leaflet$name
        )
    })
```

```
addMarkers(data = points(), popup=data_leaflet$name
```

The above function doesn't work and show me the popup output with the correct name on the map.
Error:object 'data_leaflet' not found

```
addMarkers(data = points(), popup=points$name
```

The above function doesn't work and show me the popup output with the correct name on the map.
Error:object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can someone please tell me how I can output correct name in the popup?
Thank you.